# ENS domain name restricted character set and possible workaround

Tags: ens, eth-domain, name-registrar

I am looking for an exhaustive list of ENS domain name restricted characters. Does anyone have a reference?

I also tried to work around "(anything)" as a name using UTF bold characters. It makes no sense to me but it also seems disallowed.

Is there any available workaround?